# WeChat iOS App Transport Security Settings

Tags: ios, wechat

I am integrating iOS WeChat SDK inside of my app and I am looking the "App Transport Security Settings" to add inside of the plist file.

On the examples that they have (in Chinese...) they have "Allow Arbitrary Loads" and I don't want to go by this way.

**Does anyone know more something about it?**

In addition, if he or she can add more documentation in English it will be welcome :)

Comment: Sounds like WeChat is using older, insecure HTTP/S endpoints - which is probably not a good thing. The SDK would need to be updated after they update their server endpoints.

Comment: @Daniel I think that you are right :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little of research I have seen:

- If the "App Transport Security Settings" is enable the WeChat SDK still allows to send messages.
- The url that they used is: http://pingma.qq.com. It looks like a Chinese site to check the ping. So I think that they use it in order to check if there is internet connection or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way we can integrate external apis without allowing arbitrary loads in transport security (in plist).

Comment: If the External API provides the url to add to the white list it will be possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any other way for enable "App Transport Security Settings". If you find ant other. then please let us know...

[image]